# How do I filter a relation with attribute from model?

Tags: php, laravel, eager-loading, laravel-9

I have a very complex database model in Laravel 9. I would like to get "relations" with a custom query. Currently I do this via computed properties, but these cannot be eager loaded.

Here is a simplified example:

```php
public function playlist()
{
    $fairuse = $this->show_only_fairuse;

    return Playlist::with(['songs' => function ($q) use ($fairuse) {
        $q->where('fairuse', $fairuse);
    }])->get();
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how to eager load this?

Comment: If I see your query here, everything should be fine and will be eager loaded. What do you mean computed properties? is it that $fairuse variable? Maybe the example is oversimplified too, I guess

Comment: You can not use eloquent attribute as parameter used to query database. To filter objects per eloquent attribute you would need to fetch all database data first. Investigate virtual and stored mysql generated columns, it could help in your use case or change table structure to include more columns that you could use for filtering on DB level.

Comment: @FendyHarianto - Yes, maybe I oversimplified this example. You are right everything is fine if I call this function for one model. But if I have 100 models where I have to call this function I have also 100 database queries.

Comment: @Tpojka Thanks for your comment. There are to much database data to fetch all at first. My database is not realy about songs. changing table structure is no option. :-/

Comment: what model is this method you are showing defined on? and would you really be returning every single playlist from this method? [I know this isn't the actual names and schema; just trying to understand how things relate]

Comment: @PhillippSchwarz I am telling you related options. Attribute is computed from fetched data so there is no way database know what do you mean under "attribute" hence database server can't recognise it to make filter. You can also check some of Laravel packages for DB search, maybe you realise something useful from those.

Comment: Are you try to solve the n+1 problem? Please be more descriptive, explain the "complex database" and the "computed properties".

Comment: How complex are your computed properties? Perhaps you can turn them into [generated columns](https://database.guide/what-is-a-generated-column/)